# Adding user control to GroupBox changes the user control's layout in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a WinForms application with a `GroupBox` in it. I have designed a user control which groups together a bunch of textboxes and other controls so that I can apply some custom logic to them. The user control looks like the following:
[image: User control]

I want to place this user control within my `GroupBox`, however doing so ends up affecting the layout of the controls within my user control (see below).
[image: User control in groupbox]

As you can see, my textboxes are all spread out and resized from how I want them to be. If I place this control directly on the main form or in a `Panel` (not in the `GroupBox`) the layout is maintained, however the moment I place it in the `GroupBox` everything gets messed up. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working for me was making a separate class `MyGroupBox` which extends `GroupBox`. The class is empty, but I converted the `GroupBox` on my form to this and placed the user control inside, which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The user control seems to have a different size in the two cases. Make sure it has the same size in the group box as when you place it directly on the form. If you have used a layouting control like a `FlowLayoutPanel` or a `TableLayoutPanel`, this might be of importance.

Also be aware that winforms controls inherit properties from their parent if they are not set explicitly. E.g., if you have not set the font property of the user control and its text boxes, those will be taken from the group box.

Comment: I see you are correct, when I place the user control within the GroupBox it is automatically resized. Unfortunately it does not allow me to correct the size so that it is the same as when I place it directly on the form. Is this likely due to a property of the GroupBox that I need to set?

Comment: You can enable `AutoSize` and set `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink` on the GroupBox.  That will allow it to expand to hold its contents, but that only pushes the sizing issue further up the control tree.  Whatever holds the GroupBox will need a minimum size so it does not crush the GroupBox.

Comment: @LeeHiles That is one option, however instead of having the GroupBox resize to fit the new size of the user control, I would rather have it so that the user control isn't resizing itself when placed in the GroupBox

Comment: It is difficult to give you detailed advice, since we don't know how the user control is constructed. It depends much on the settings of the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties of the controls in the user control and whether they are imbedded in some container control that influences the layout.